# one-way functions vs. secret-coin CRHFs

Tags: cr.crypto-security, hash-function, relativization, one-way-function

Is there any paper which can be used to show that there can be no relativizing construction of a [secret-coin Collision-Resistant Hash Family](http://www.cs.bu.edu/~reyzin/papers/hash.ps) from a one-way function and unlike [this paper](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-45760-7_7.pdf), does not claim to show more than it actually shows?

The second link shows *some* result, and I *believe* that what it actually shows
is strong enough, but I'm quite hesitant to cite that paper because the author
 writes "we show that relative to an oracle non-interactive weakly-binding honest-receiver statistically-secret commitments schemes do not exist" despite his definition of "non-interactive weakly-binding honest-receiver statistically-secret bit commitment scheme"s corresponding to an *otherwise* semi-honest receiver that is allowed to choose its "random bits" maliciously, and requiring perfect completeness and gives a definition of a "black-box one-way permutation" that does not require [injectivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function).

Comment: It might be helpful to make the question more self-contained. As such, it starts off right now with a cryptic reference to another paper.